# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

Below is my code, I am not able to resolve this error. Any help is appreciated. I am trying to update a table in my database.

```
    public function updateUnit($params){
    $user = 'monil';
    $password = 'Masters123';   
    $dbh = new \PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=tcsdb', $user, $password);

    $task=array(':UnitCode'=>$params['UnitCode'],':UnitDescription'=>$params['UnitDescription']    ,
      ':UnitName'=>$params['UnitName'], ':UnitID'=>$params['UnitID']);
    echo $params['UnitID'];

    $sth = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE unit SET UnitCode = :UnitCode,'
        . 'UnitDescription = :UnitDescription,UnitName = :UnitName WHERE UnitId=:UnitId');
    $sth->execute($task); 

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Parameter names used in execute()/binding should be exact match for the parameter names used in the SQL query. That's the point of named parameters.

You need to check every placeholder in SQL, whether its name matches the name used in execute(), bindParam() or bindValue().

In your case, `:UnitID` is not the same as `:UnitId`, there is a difference in the letter case.

In a rare case, the error can be caused by improper placeholder name. The only characters allowed are `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`.

Also, you cannot use the same placeholder more than once, unless the emulation mode is turned on.

Answer (score 1):

The same error arise when you missed : colon while creating statement.

ex:
 Below statement throws **invalid parameter error** as **password** in VALUES is missing : colon.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password) VALUES (:username, password)');
```

Answer (score 1):

same errors may occur if you use a "." dot in bindParam

ex.

```
$query = "select * from t where t1 = :foo.bar";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute([':foo.bar' => 'blah']);
```